# How do I convert an NSInteger to the corresponding words in objective-c with indian rupees

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsinteger

```
NSInteger someNumber = 211242;
```

I would like to know some function so that would return a string similar to *"Two lakh eleven thousand two hundred forty-two Rupees only"*

Comment: Use NSNumberFormatter

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I tried given link and got `two hundred eleven thousand two hundred forty-two` . How to get `Two lakh eleven thousand` instead of `two hundred eleven thousand`?

Comment: @RajeshkumarR - its the sample link, how to work on

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution to do that. You have to use **NSNumberFormatter**.

```
    NSInteger anInt = 11242043;
    NSString *wordNumber;

    //convert to words
    NSNumber *numberValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:anInt]; //needs to be NSNumber!
    NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterSpellOutStyle];
    wordNumber = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:numberValue];
    NSLog(@"Answer: %@", wordNumber);
```

**Swift Solution:**

```
extension Int {
    var asWord:String {
        let numberValue = NSNumber(integer: self)
        var formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .SpellOutStyle
        return "\(formatter.stringFromNumber(self)!)"
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this and got `two hundred eleven thousand two hundred forty-two` . How to get `Two lakh eleven thousand` instead of `two hundred eleven thousand`?

Comment: Understood your question. Bitter truth is, there is no support for this. You have to write your own number formatter manually